# Javascript on-click toggle

Tags: javascript

I have some code that when a user clicks away from a side-bar the side-bar closes, How do I change it so when a user clicks a link the side-bar also closes and as well as from the side bar

Example - if I was to click the word Home, it would then hide the side-bar.

```js
//hidding side header on click outside header
$body.on('mousedown touchstart click', function(e) {
  if (!($(e.target).closest('.page_header_side').length) && !($sideHeader.hasClass('header_side_sticked'))) {
    $sideHeader.removeClass('active-slide-side-header');
    $body.removeClass('active-side-header slide-right');
    $body.parent().removeClass('html-active-push-header');
    var $toggler = $('.toggle_menu_side');
    if (($toggler).hasClass('active')) {
      $toggler.removeClass('active');
    }
  }
});
} //sideHeader check
```

```html
<header class="page_header_side header_slide header-special header_side_right ds">

     <div class="scrollbar-macosx">
      <div class="side_header_inner">
       <p class="text-right mb-0 close-wrapper"><a href="">×</a></p>

       <div class="widget widget_recent_posts">

                                <h3 class="widget-title"><a href="index">Home</a></h3>
        
       </div>
                            
                            <div class="widget widget_recent_posts">

                                <h3 class="widget-title"><a href="#overview">Overview</a></h3>
        
       </div>
                            
                            <div class="widget widget_recent_posts">

                                <h3 class="widget-title"><a href="#about">About</a></h3>
        
       </div>
```

attached is the image of the sidebar when opened

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would turn all of your close code into a function like so:

```
function closeMenu(){
    if (!($(e.target).closest('.page_header_side').length) && !($sideHeader.hasClass('header_side_sticked'))) {
        $sideHeader.removeClass('active-slide-side-header');
        $body.removeClass('active-side-header slide-right');
        $body.parent().removeClass('html-active-push-header');
        var $toggler = $('.toggle_menu_side');
        if (($toggler).hasClass('active')) {
            $toggler.removeClass('active');
        }
     }
});
```

Then I would put the same handler that you have on the body on the links of the menu. Let's say your menu has an id of menu

So you would have:

```
$('body', '#menu a').onClick(function(){
    closeMenu();
});
```

This will add the handler to the body as well as all a tags within the menu.

Comment: I tried what you suggested,  and it did not work, please see the HMTL to understand the full HTML

Answer (score 0):

With the given code this is what I have done:

```js
//hidding side header on click outside header
$('.scrollbar-macosx').on('click', function(e) {

    //$sideHeader.removeClass('active-slide-side-header');
    //$body.removeClass('active-side-header slide-right');
    //$body.parent().removeClass('html-active-push-header');
    //if you want to keep playing with adding and removing classes them:
    //if (($toggler).hasClass('active')) {
      $('#elementToHide').fadeOut();
    //}

  });
//sideHeader check
```

And them your html:

```html
<header class="page_header_side header_slide header-special header_side_right ds">
   <div class="scrollbar-macosx" id="elementToHide">
      <div class="side_header_inner">
         <p class="text-right mb-0 close-wrapper"><a href="#">×</a></p>
         <div class="widget widget_recent_posts">
            <h3 class="widget-title"><a href="#">Home</a></h3>
         </div>
         <div class="widget widget_recent_posts">
            <h3 class="widget-title"><a href="#">Overview</a></h3>
         </div>
         <div class="widget widget_recent_posts">
            <h3 class="widget-title"><a href="#">About</a></h3>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</header>
```

Here is the fiddle : [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Qiqke/06nxzLs8/)